# Best way to request data from server every x seconds

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, settimeout

I created a very simple example. I try to request a value from my server every X seconds, in this case i simply want to get a random number, every second.
This solution works, but unfortunately there seems that an infinite loop occurs after a while, which leads to a crash. I also get over 100k Errors after a while `net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES`.

```
request_data(1000);

function request_data(intervall) {            
    $.post('ajax.php', {
        cmd: "get_random_number"
    }, function (returned_data, status) {
        if (status === "success") {
            $("#result_output").html(returned_data);
            setInterval(function() {
                request_data(intervall);
            }, intervall);
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="result_output></p>
```

```php
// ajax.php
<?php
    $cmd  = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "cmd");
    if (isset($cmd) && $cmd == "get_random_number") {
        echo rand(5, 15);
    }
```

Whats the best solution to achieve this?

Comment: If you're just getting a random number, why not do it on the client side to save bandwidth and server processing time? If this is a simplified version of your logic just for this question, then look at using websockets.

Comment: surely it will be infinite as youre using setInterval not setTimeout

Comment: Change `setInterval` to `setTimeout`. You are making `O(2^n)` calls.

Comment: why not use websockets or longpolling?

Comment: Sending a request to a server every seconds is very heavy to a server. If you are achieving to have a real time application. Use [nodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/).

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, because it is just a simple example for stackoverflow so everyone can understand what the code does.

Comment: Thats fine, as I said in that case investigate websockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by simply replacing `setInterval` with `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a setInterval, and then inside this do an ajax call. One of the parameters you can set in the $.ajax is a timeout - so that you can stop multiple ajax calls stacking up and causing problems.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '',
    type: '',
    data: {},
    timeout: 3000,
    success: function(data){
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

For more info on the parameters, see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

As Derek has pointed out, this is because, you are making 2^n calls since the setInterval is inside the function itself.

Try it like this instead

```
window.setInterval(1000, request_data);

function request_data() {            
    $.post('ajax.php', {
        cmd: "get_random_number"
    }, function (returned_data, status) {
        if (status === "success") {
            $("#result_output").html(returned_data);
        }
    });
}
```